# Swift UIViewController tableView.reloadData nil wrapping on second call

Tags: ios, uitableview

Did many searches without success. In my view controller on viewDidLoad I call a function named callJson. It then sets the data that is bound to a UITableView. This all works great the first time. Now I also have a UIRefreshControl and when I pull it, it makes a call to the same function, callJson, and here on the second attempt do I get the infamous error of

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
on self.tableView.reloadData()

Here is the function that makes the request to the json and says to reload the table with the new data.

```
func callJson(){
    JSONOperations.sharedInstance.JsonRequest(roadType: Helpers.RoadWayTypes.ALERTS, imageId: nil) {(json: NSDictionary) in
        do {
            //unbox alerts
            let aData: Alerts = try unbox(dictionary: json as! UnboxableDictionary)
            self.alerts = aData
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

tableView setting cell data

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let alertD = alerts?.Alerts[indexPath.row] {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AlertTableViewCell") as! AlertTableViewCell
        cell.name.text = alertD.Summary
        cell.icon.image = Helpers.listImage24dp(id: alertD.TOA)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        if alertD.Url.characters.count == 0 {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            return cell
        }
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.name.textColor = UIColor.blue
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

When I set a break point just prior to self.tableView.reloadData() and step into, it goes to the outlet defined but then throws the nil error. I'm not sure if I need to set things up differently in the tableView or something else as it works correctly the first time. Any help/ideas to try are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have set tableview's outlet?

Comment: Yes, otherwise, it wouldn't work the first time unless for some reason the outlet is getting dropped between the first call and the second which if so I wouldn't understand why or how to go about reinstating it.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

**Reason:** tableview reload should happen in the UI thread.

Comment: Putting this in the closure didn't change anything. Still works the first time but not the second. Same error.